# Avoid combination of hyphen and space using a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm currently writing a very specific regex for a firstname field, that has several requirements. One of them is that spaces are not allowed before or after hyphens. For this, I have used a negative lookahead:

```
(?!.*(\s\-))
```

as part of the regex:

```
^(?!ß)(?!.*(\s\-))(?!(.)\1{2})(?!.*\s{2})(?!.*\'{2})(?!.*\-{2})[a-zA-ZßöüäÜÖÄ\s\-\']{2,30}(?<![\s\-])$
```

It does return a mismatch for:

```
asdf -asdf
```

but not for:

```
asdf- asdf
```

The latter also need to return an error. What am I missing?

Comment: Uri Agassi As is ocasionally the case, your edit is horrible. You made the question less understandable. From the original post, it looks like the OP intended to quote the codes with `{}`, but you additionally quoted with the usual backticks, so it became confusing.

Comment: @sawa: Uri won't be notified of your comment unless you @-reply them :)

Comment: @Amal Murali Uri has not made a post, so it does not make a difference. Your edit was correct, and was messed by Unihedron. It seems like I reverted to your previous version right after you did.

Comment: Unihedron Your edit is wrong. "as part of ..." is in the middle of a sentence. It should not be capitalized.

Comment: @sawa: It does. From [*How do comment `@` replies work?* on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/220538): "*You can explicitly notify one (1) other user if they have a current (non-deleted) comment on the post __or__ their name appears anywhere in the revision history*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assert the other combination of hyphens and whitespaces absent in your string also:

```
(?!.*(\s\-))(?!.*(\-\s))
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works - I tried that the first time but it did not work then. I must have made a mistake somewhere - new to this whole regex business

Comment: It needs to be right after the `^` or it won't work as expected. Also, you don't escape `-`s there.

Comment: @pguardiario Good point about escaping `-`s, nice catch! However, there's a regex matching mode in ruby which is anchored, so I left out `^$` as, per OP's example, he is using anchored matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your pattern in a more simple way that avoids many problems and makes your pattern more efficient, example:

```
^(?=.{2,30}$)(?!(.)\1{2})[a-zA-ZöüäÜÖÄ]+(?:[-'\s][a-zA-ZßöüäÜÖÄ]+)*$
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would avoid validation of things like
{asds'-asd}
Hence, they are not the same, eventhough I see your point.

Comment: @Amin: You can easily replace `[-'\s]` with an alternation that fits your need, something like: `(?:'-?|[-\s])` (or whatever you want). It will be better than parsing all the string each time you have a lookahead.

Comment: I don't know how ":" works exactly, yet. I will have to look into it first, since I'm still having difficulties to understand all of it properly. Thank you!

Comment: @Amin: `(?:...)` is only a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is probably a negative lookahead right after the ^:

```
/^(?!.*(\s-|-\s))#{main_pattern}/
```